# Bind Multiple lines of text to a label

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to bind large text data to a label dynamically. I will get some large text data from a datasource and have to bind it to lable. So how to display multiple lines of text in a label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest would be just

```
string value = "one\r\ntwo\r\nthree";

label.Text = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```

But if you have a list of strings you can try a repeater approach

```
<asp:Label ID="label" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Container.DataItem %> <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Label>
```

And the code

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>()
    {
        "One", "Two", "Three"
    };

repeater.DataSource = listOfStrings;
repeater.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case use of literal is better because you write html in literal from your code like this:

```
Literal1.Text = "Hello<br/>"+"How are you?"....
```

Or you can use Text box as set property TextMode=Multiline and readonly=True to behave as Label

Answer (score 1):

You could just try this

```
Label.AutoSize = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know in what "units" you will measure the text length. but adding `<br />` to a `ur_string` will start a new line.

**EDITED**

this is not valid for all `asp.net` controls. just `asp.net label` renders as `html span`, so for label `<br />` will have a desired effect.

Comment: Can you explain what a `ur_string` is, and what difference would the units make?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes `ur_string` just a variable. difference in "units" i mean different font size will give different text length. so the "unit" is up to OP.